# Increment the value of a map

Tags: c++, dictionary

need your help and better if you can help me fast. It is very trivial problem but still can't understand what exactly i need to put in one line.

The following code i have

```
for (busRequest = apointCollection.begin(); busRequest != apointCollection.end(); busRequest++)
{
    double Min = DBL_MAX;
    int station = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < newStations; i++)
    {

        distance = sqrt(pow((apointCollection2[i].x - busRequest->x1), 2) + pow((apointCollection2[i].y - busRequest->y1), 2));
        if (distance < Min)
        {
            Min = distance;
            station = i;

        }
    }

    if (people.find(station) == people.end())
    {
        people.insert(pair<int, int>(station, i));
    }

    else
    {
        how can i increment "i" if the key of my statation is already in the map.
    }

}
```

Just briefly what i do , i take the first busrequest go to the second loop take the first station and find the minimum distance. After i go over the second loop , i add that station with minimum distance to my map . After i proceed with all my loops and if there is the same station , i need to increment it , so it means that that station is using two times and etc.

I need the help just give me hint or provide the line that i need to add.

I thank you in advance and waiting for your help.

Comment: YourMap[YourKey]++

Comment: thanks !!!! You helped me much!!

Comment: :) glad that I helped. I will put it in an answer please mark it as an answer.

Comment: Feel free. And edit your post with the new code and the new question

Comment: FYI, don't use `pow(x,2)` as there is more overhead in calling and executing the function than multiplying two values, `pow(x,2) == x*x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And I think you meant `Min Distance` instead of `i`? Check and let me know.

```
for (busRequest = apointCollection.begin(); busRequest != apointCollection.end(); busRequest++)
{
    double Min = DBL_MAX;
    int station = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < newStations; i++)
    {

        distance = sqrt(pow((apointCollection2[i].x - busRequest->x1), 2) + pow((apointCollection2[i].y - busRequest->y1), 2));
        if (distance < Min)
        {
            Min = distance;
            station = i;

        }
    }

    if (people.find(station) == people.end())
    {
        people.insert(pair<int, int>(station, i)); // here???
    }

    else
    {
        // This routine will increment the value if the key already exists. If it doesn't exist it will create it for you
        YourMap[YourKey]++;
    }

}
```

Comment: First step tell me please if i use after loops for (auto it = people.begin(); it != people.end(); it++)
 {
  cout << it->first << ";" << it->second << endl;
 } If id 0 has the number of station , does this id correspond to the station i used before?

Comment: @mishaOstapchuk edit your original post. Put THERE the new code, new question, new error (if any) and I will answer here. Follow this pattern on Stack Overflow

Comment: i posted at the end , i know it is out of rules but i can't post a question today.

Comment: @mishaOstapchuk but I didn't get what you mean.. Did you try Step-Over your code?? using f-10? do that and see the values of every variable on every statement

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you can directly access a map key without inserting it. C++ will automatically create it with default value.
In your case, if a `station` is not present in `people` map and you will access `people[station]` then `people[station]` will automatically be set to `0` ( default value of `int` is 0 ).

So you can just do this:

```
if (people[station] == 0)
{
    // Do something
    people[station] = station; // NOTE: i is not accessible here! check ur logic
}
else
{
    people[station]++;
}
```

Also: In your code `i` cannot be accessed inside IF condition to insert into people map.

Comment: i added int i  = 1 after the first loop as well where i use Min=dbl_max. And my key should correspond the station that  has the minimum distance. It means if i have station number 75 it should increment after if this station appears again in my map

Comment: No you didn't. I cannot see that in your code at least.

Comment: yes i didn't send it with the code . Sorry for that